# Composable Kotlin App crashes when calling navController.navigate to all screens but one

Tags: kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

Not sure what is wrong, I have my navController that im passing to CreateScheduledItemScreen to use it from there. But I cant navigate to anyscreen BUT Home screen from CreateScheduledItemScreen, if I do the app crashes.

The screens works and can be navigated to from the bottomBar.

```
@Composable
fun MotivationApp(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: MotivationViewModel = MotivationViewModel(),
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
) {
    viewModel.fillPhotoArray()
    // Get current back stack entry
    val backStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    // Get the name of the current screen
    val currentScreen = MotivateScreenNavHost.valueOf(
        backStackEntry?.destination?.route ?: MotivateScreenNavHost.Home.name
    )

    Scaffold(bottomBar = {
        BottomBar(navHostController = navController,
            currentScreen = currentScreen,
            canNavigateBack = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null,
            navigateUp = { navController.navigateUp() })
    }, topBar = {
        MotivationTopAppBar(navHostController = navController,
            currentScreen = currentScreen,
            canNavigateBack = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null,
            navigateUp = { navController.navigateUp() })
    }) { innerPadding ->

        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = MotivateScreenNavHost.Home.name,
            modifier = modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            composable(route = MotivateScreenNavHost.Home.name) {
                viewModel.setDates(homeScreen())
            }
            composable(route = MotivateScreenNavHost.Setting.name) {
                val context = LocalContext.current
                SettingsScreen()
            }
            composable(route = MotivateScreenNavHost.Profile.name) {
                val context = LocalContext.current
                ProfileScreen()
            }
            composable(route = MotivateScreenNavHost.AddScheduledItem.name) {
                val context = LocalContext.current
                CreateScheduledItemScreen(
                    viewModel.getPhotos(),
                    viewModel.getDates(),
                    navController,
                    viewModel
                )
            }
            composable(route = MotivateScreenNavHost.CreateItemInputScreen.name) {
                CreateItemInputScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if I would change navController.navigate(MotivateScreenNavHost.CreateItemInputScreen.name) -> navController.navigate(MotivateScreenNavHost.Home.name) the app does not crash.

Any ideas?

```
@Composable
fun CreateScheduledItemScreen(
    photo: ArrayList<Int>,
    date: ArrayList<Int>,
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: MotivationViewModel
) {
    val mContext = LocalContext.current
    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 185.dp), contentPadding = PaddingValues(
        start = 12.dp, top = 16.dp, end = 12.dp, bottom = 16.dp
    ), content = {
        items(photo.size) { index ->
            Card(
                backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(6.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                elevation = 0.dp,
            ) {
                Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                        val mCategory = when (photo[index]) {
                            R.drawable.training -> 1
                            R.drawable.travel -> 2
                            R.drawable.study -> 3
                            R.drawable.meetingjpg -> 4
                            R.drawable.party -> 5
                            R.drawable.doctor -> 6
                            R.drawable.dentist -> 7
                            R.drawable.groceries -> 8
                            else -> {
                                9
                            }
                        }
                        viewModel.setCategory(mCategory)
                        navController.navigate(MotivateScreenNavHost.CreateItemInputScreen.name)
                    }) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(photo[index]),
                        contentDescription = "Test",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(150.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape)
                            .border(
                                1.5.dp,
                                androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                                CircleShape
                            )
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = when (photo[index]) {
                            R.drawable.training -> "Training"
                            R.drawable.travel -> "Travel"
                            R.drawable.study -> "Study"
                            R.drawable.meetingjpg -> "Meeting"
                            R.drawable.party -> "Party"
                            R.drawable.doctor -> "Doctor"
                            R.drawable.dentist -> "Dentist"
                            R.drawable.groceries -> "Groceries"
                            else -> {
                                "Other"
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    Text(text = "${date[0]} ${date[1]} ${date[2]}")
                }

            }
        }
    })
}
```

I have tried a lot. Kinda new to composable and this navigate through composable.
I am expecting that when I click the button the new screen shows.

Error:

```
2022-11-07 15:44:09.622 24752-24752/com.pocketqueens.chefforhire E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pocketqueens.chefforhire, PID: 24752
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.pocketqueens.chefforhire.activity.CreateScheduledItemScreenKt$CreateScheduledItemScreen$1$1$1.invoke(CreateScheduledItemScreen.kt:92)
        at com.pocketqueens.chefforhire.activity.CreateScheduledItemScreenKt$CreateScheduledItemScreen$1$1$1.invoke(CreateScheduledItemScreen.kt:45)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:145)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2375)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2666)
        at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt.Surface-F-jzlyU(Surface.kt:137)
        at androidx.compose.material.CardKt.Card-F-jzlyU(Card.kt:68)
        at com.pocketqueens.chefforhire.activity.CreateScheduledItemScreenKt$CreateScheduledItemScreen$1$1.invoke(CreateScheduledItemScreen.kt:39)
        at com.pocketqueens.chefforhire.activity.CreateScheduledItemScreenKt$CreateScheduledItemScreen$1$1.invoke(CreateScheduledItemScreen.kt:38)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:135)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridItemsSnapshot.Item(LazyGridItemProviderImpl.kt:97)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridItemProviderImpl.Item(LazyGridItemProviderImpl.kt:119)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$createContentLambda$1$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:119)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$createContentLambda$1$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:118)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$createContentLambda$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:118)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$createContentLambda$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:110)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$subcompose$2$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:771)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$subcompose$2$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:448)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3248)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3238)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3238)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3173)
2022-11-07 15:44:09.623 24752-24752/com.pocketqueens.chefforhire E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:587)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:950)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3848)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3848)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:519)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:468)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:441)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:432)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:421)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$Scope.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:733)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutMeasureScopeImpl.measure-0kLqBqw(LazyLayoutMeasureScope.kt:118)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyMeasuredItemProvider.getAndMeasure-ednRnyU(LazyMeasuredItemProvider.kt:44)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyMeasuredLineProvider.getAndMeasure-bKFJvoY(LazyMeasuredLineProvider.kt:70)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridMeasureKt.measureLazyGrid-zIfe3eg(LazyGridMeasure.kt:141)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridKt$rememberLazyGridMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyGrid.kt:340)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridKt$rememberLazyGridMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke(LazyGrid.kt:190)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$2$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyLayout.kt:74)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$2$1.invoke(LazyLayout.kt:70)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:591)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:103)
        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:405)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:343)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1077)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1073)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1073)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:36)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:341)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1135)
2022-11-07 15:44:09.623 24752-24752/com.pocketqueens.chefforhire E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release$default(LayoutNode.kt:1126)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure-sdFAvZA(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:309)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:434)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:330)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.measureAndLayout(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:774)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner.measureAndLayout$default(Owner.kt:216)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:999)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20210)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4290)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19042)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4290)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19042)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4290)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19042)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4317)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4290)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19042)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:801)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3311)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3115)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2022-11-07 15:44:09.630 24752-24752/com.pocketqueens.chefforhire I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24752 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you please include the error that you receive on navigation to other screens?

Comment: Not related to your problem but you are not supposed to initialise your ViewModel that way.

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodels-source-of-truth

Comment: Thank you @EmmanuelMtali will have a look at that.

Comment: @BenjaminCharais

Error added.

Comment: what happens on line 92 in CreateScheduledItemScreen.kt ?

Comment: I'm thinking this looks like photos or date aren't populated. Might be worth to try to fill them with some default values for making the page. It might be an issue with how view model is providing them to the View itself

Comment: @Chris

It was this:
`
Text(text = "${date[0]} ${date[1]} ${date[2]}")
`

And that was the problem..... After commenting it out it worked splendid. Which is weird seeing as it was working and showing all along... Not really sure why this occurd.
Thank you

Comment: Great. Well done working it out.